# Inline js works, external file doesn't

Tags: javascript, html

When I'm using inline javascript code, everything works fine. As soon as I try to run the code from my script.js, it doesn't work anymore.

I already searched for this problem in google and it always ends up having something to do the DOM and onload or something like that (sorry I'm new to this whole html/css/js thing). It didn't help though, I'm already using defer and I tried onLoad.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@5/dist/backdrop.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script defer src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1"></script>
    <script defer src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@5"></script>
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">

      <button id="myButton" class="button" title="button">My Button</button>   

      <div class="columns svg">
        <div class="column is-one-third">
          <div class="box">
            <object type="image/svg+xml" data="SVG/Abbildung1.svg"></object> 
          </div>
        </div>

    </div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
/* SVG */ 
document.getElementById('ebk').addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
   this.style.fill = "red";
});
document.getElementById('ebk').addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
   this.style.fill = "black";
});
tippy('#myButton', {
   content: "I'm a Tippy tooltip!",
});
```

I get these errors:

Uncaught ReferenceError: tippy is not defined

^ this is my problem

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

^ this is just annoying, but my page still works fine. Is it because of the SVG not loading fast enough or something like that?

**EDIT:**

Tippy works now, I created another external .js file and seperated the code for the SVG and tippy, and now it works. Looks like the problem is that I got

```html
<script type="text/javascript" href="../script.js"></script>
```

in my SVG file. I don't really know why, since I'm new to this.

Though the "addEventListener" error ist still not gone.

Comment: You're running your code too early. Put your JS file at the end of the document, before the closing body tag or wrap it in a window.load function

Comment: I tried both, it doesn't help.

Comment: Where is your element with the ID of `ebk` in `document.getElementById('ebk')`?

Comment: Its inside a SVG file, its a <text>

Comment: since your script fails at the `document.getElementById('ebk')` line, then the `tippy('#myButton'` could not possibly run - assuming the code you've shown is `script.js` - so, there's no way you could get both errors

Comment: I get both errors, the document.getElementById('ebk') error doesn't affect my website, it still works. The bigger problem is the tippy error, since it works when I write the code in my html file.

Comment: For testing purposes, you could stick it in the `setTimeout()` method and start with something like 2s, and continue to lower the time until you see the time difference. Also, have you checked in the developer console if your browser, under the network tab, to see the load time difference between inline and external loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register the `onload` event on the object element and do your actions when it's fired.

First define an id for the object element:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@5/dist/backdrop.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script defer src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1"></script>
    <script defer src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@5"></script>
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">

      <button id="myButton" class="button" title="button">My Button</button>   

      <div class="columns svg">
        <div class="column is-one-third">
          <div class="box">
            <object id="svg" type="image/svg+xml" data="SVG/Abbildung1.svg"></object> 
          </div>
        </div>

    </div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Then register the `onload` event on the object:

```
var svg = document.getElementById('svg')
svg.onload = function () {
var svgDoc = svg.contentDocument;  // Access to object document
/* SVG */ 
svgDoc.getElementById('ebk').addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
   this.style.fill = "red";
});
svgDoc.getElementById('ebk').addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
   this.style.fill = "black";
});
tippy('#myButton', {
   content: "I'm a Tippy tooltip!",
});
}
```

Be shure to move the script tag at the HTML page end.

Comment: `Be sure to move the script tag at the HTML page end` why? doesn't `defer` attribute result in the javascript being executed after the document has been parsed?

Comment: Thank you, but now it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onload' of null".

Comment: @user3566608 - did you notice `<object id="svg"` ... the  **id** attribute?

Comment: @user3566608 the id of the object element equals the one used in getElementById?

Comment: yes my object has id="svg" and the id of the object doesn't equal any other one used in getElementById. Is it important to mention that I got <script type="text/javascript" href="../script.js"></script> at the end of my SVG File?

Comment: @user3566608 I made an edit, you have to use `contentDocument` to access `object` internal values

Comment: Thank you so much! That was exactly what I was looking for, now I don't even need to to have <script type="text/javascript" href="../script.js"></script> in my SVG and everything just works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing `defer` from the `tippy.js` script tag?

> The defer attribute tells the browser that it should go on working with the page, and load the script “in background”, then run the script when it loads. Scripts with defer never block the page.

It seems like your script.js file depends on tippy.js to work correctly.

And for:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

Seems like you don't have any HTML element with ID 'ebk', so you can't attach an event to an element that doesn't exist.

Comment: I tried that, all different kinds of combinations, but it sadly still doesn't work. 'ebk' is inside the SVG File I'm loading. The code actually works, I'm just wondering why the errors keeps popping up.

Comment: @user3566608 https://codesandbox.io/s/58675881-lp1l4 this should work, I wrapped your script.js in a document.onload function.